# checkbox javascript нужна помощь

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос таков. На стороннем сайте есть форма в которой есть `checkbox`, как при помощи `javascript` выбрать нужный мне `checkbox` при использовании встроенного приложения в mozilla `Простой редактор javascript`. Вот кусок формы с сайта.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" title="Отметить все колонки таблицы">
```

Comment: вместо `type="checkbox"` напишите `type="radio"` и всегда сможете выбрать только одну из них.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Прошу прощения, вы поняли скорее всего не правильно. Надо, что бы выбрало нужный чекбокс при использовании моего кода на стороннем сайте.

Comment: @yuriyurekt, отредактируй вопрос добавив **всю необходимую** информацию. Сейчас непонятно что ты хочешь сделать. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: @yuriyurekt Ну тогда вы не правильно задали вопрос, по пунктам давайте обясните подробно, поправьте вопрос.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Готово.

Comment: @yuriyurekt Вопрос опять не полный, что за код у вас и как вообще оно должно работать на другом сайте? 
нужно по пунктам. изучите как можно задавать корректный вопрос.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan исправил.

Comment: @yuriyurekt Приведите еще подробную информацию

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Куда ещё подробней? Представьте себе: вы зашли на одностраничный сайт на котором есть 2 чекбокса .У вас есть плагин который может запускать ваш js в браузере.  При помощи какой команды js можно выбрать один из них?

Comment: @yuriyurekt Вы вообще знаете jquery или javascript?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Я до редактирования своего вопроса писал, что я юзвер в js. Честно, я читал как это сделать, но не пришел к выходу из этой ситуации. Я терпеть не могу задавать на этом сайте вопросы, так как здесь все слишком "зазнатые юзеры". Вечно стебут кого-то, придираются, например как вы сейчас. Что вам просто мешает подтолкнуть на данный ответ? Вас ведь никто не заставляет заходить в этот вопрос и отвечать. В этом же суть, если человек не понимает, он спрашивает. Если вас затрудняет ответить на этот вопрос, проходите мимо. Накипело.

Comment: @yuriyurekt Правильно вы сделали изменение в вопросе, но это было и для ваших нужд, можете задать кому нибуть ваш вопрос который был изначально и он толком не поймет что вы хотите сделать.
а так понятно что вам нужно и ответ на ваш вопрос будет, скиньте еще и форму с сайта а не только ту строку и я приведу рабочий пример для вас.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59490/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-yuriyurekt).

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример простого `JavaScript` кода который решит ваш вопрос:
Как я понял из нашего обсуждения в чате у вас структура такая на стороннем сайте:

```
<th class="select-all">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" title="Отметить все колонки таблицы">
</th>
```

Вам нужно выбрать вот этот `checkbox`:

Из кода видно что его можем выбрать по классу его родителя `class="select-all"`.

И тут просто 3 строки `Javascript` кода, первая строка выбирает родителя, вторая по нему ищет сам тот `checkbox` который вам нужно,а третья строка поставляет `птичку` (выбирает ваш `checkbox`)․

```
var tmp_th = document.getElementsByClassName('select-all');
var my_checkbox = tmp_th[0].childNodes[1];
my_checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

Если хотите проверить что выбрали нужный элемент просто напишите после кода такую строку `console.log(my_checkbox);` и вам вывидит в консоле выбранный элемент.